# Remove blue border from input @material-tailwind/react Input

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using `Input` from `@material-tailwind/react` in my `react.js` project

**Code**

```
<Input
   label="First Name"
    containerProps={{ className: "min-w-[72px]" }}
    value={first}
    onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.target.value)}
/>
```

**Output**

[image]

> I'm getting this mix of blue & black border

Answer (score 0):

You can use *outline-none* class to remove the "blue border"